# jquery appending elements but wont stop looping

Tags: jquery, append

i have created a situation where `elements` gett `appendto` a `ul` after a count down , but i do not want an existing `li` to be replaced or duplicated, i only want new li's by id. i have tried empty the entire `ul` and replacing it with the new 1 or 2 and old 9-100 but this takes to long depending on how many elemnts are in the ul ,and it causes load to lag... so i just want single ones tht are new any ideas on how i can tweak my code?

jquery:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "morphelo/splash.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "x=int",
            datatype: "html",
            success: function(data){
                var Data = $.parseJSON(data);

                var Clus = Data.clu;
                console.log(Clus);
                var cl = Clus.length; 
                var aci = new Array(); var i = 0;

                if(cl > 0){
                    var clu = $('.clu_holder').children('.clu'); // every clutch li
                    $.each(clu,function(x,y){
                        var clutchid = $(this).attr('id');

                        $.each(Clus,function(){
                            if(this.ckey == clutchid){
                                // dont worrie about me
                            }else{
                                // put me in coach
                                var newLi = '<li class="clu" id="'+this.ckey+'">clu</li>';
                                $(newLi).appendTo('.clu_holder').fadeIn();
                            }
                        });

                    });


                }else{

                }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your problem is that you are doing a loop inside a loop. I think i would do something like this. I havent testet it, and it is just a quick mock up.

```
if(cl > 0){
   var holder = $('.clu_holder');
   $.each(Clus,function(){
       if(holder.find("#"+ this.ckey).length == 0){
           var newLi = '<li class="clu" id="'+this.ckey+'">clu</li>';
            holder.append(newLi).fadeIn();
        }
    });
 }
```

What i have changed is:

Saving the holder element, so you can use it to append your elements without having to search for it each time.

Only looping 1 collection, and since you have the id on the element, you can find it by searching.